# How to set up class for json?

Tags: c#, json

I am working with [opentdb.com](https://opentdb.com/api_config.php) api and have no idea how to access data in this json:

```
{  
   "response_code":0,
   "results": [  
      {  
         "category":"Animals",
         "type":"multiple",
         "difficulty":"easy",
         "question":"What is the scientific name for modern day humans?",
         "correct_answer":"Homo Sapiens",
         "incorrect_answers":[  
            "Homo Ergaster",
            "Homo Erectus",
            "Homo Neanderthalensis"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "category":"Entertainment: Cartoon & Animations",
         "type":"multiple",
         "difficulty":"easy",
         "question":"Who voices for Ruby in the animated series RWBY?",
         "correct_answer":"Lindsay Jones",
         "incorrect_answers":[  
            "Tara Strong",
            "Jessica Nigri",
            "Hayden Panettiere"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using Newtonsoft.Json and i tried this with only 1 Question but im geting an error that says that key value is wrong..

```
class Trivia
{

    public Trivia(string json)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jresults = jObject["results"];
        category = (string)jresults["category"];
        type = (string)jresults["type"];
        difficulty = (string)jresults["difficulty"];
        question = (string)jresults["question"];
        correct_answer = (string)jresults["correct_answer"];

        incorrect_answers = jresults["incorrect_answers"].ToArray();
    }

    public string category { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string difficulty { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string correct_answer { get; set; }
    public Array incorrect_answers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Enjoy](https://app.quicktype.io?share=q24pstvod6bEdJfHDi3n)

Comment: `results` is an array, so `results` does not contain `category`. Hint: `results[0]["category"]` might work better.

Comment: Nothing in that class makes sense, you never pass a JSON string to manually deserialize it, the JsonConvert class is there for a reason. Paste your JSON here: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp and done.

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy from json text and in new class in visual studio **Edit-->Paste Special-->Paste JSON As Classes**

```
public class Rootobject
        {
            public int response_code { get; set; }
            public Result[] results { get; set; }
        }

        public class Result
        {
            public string category { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string difficulty { get; set; }
            public string question { get; set; }
            public string correct_answer { get; set; }
            public string[] incorrect_answers { get; set; }
        }
```

using namespace

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

response is value get from your service

```
var outdeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);
```